# Multiple shopping cart discounts based on subtotal

Tags: discount, promotions

I have set up multiple shopping cart promotion rules and sometimes, more than one rule is applied. What I want is that all discount rates are applied to subtotal and not one after the other.

Example:

- Shopping cart rule of 10% discount for orders with subtotal greater than $50.
- Coupon code for 10% discount.

When I have a product of $100 in my shopping cart and enter coupon, both rules are applied. What happens: first 10% discount is applied: $100 - $10 = $90. After this, second 10% discount is applied: $90 - $9 = $81.

What I want is both 10% discount based on subtotal: $100 - $10 - $10 = $80.

I've tried setting equal priorities, but this doesn't work.
Anyone knows how to fix this?

Comment: Perhaps this is what you are looking for http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/49393/modify-shopping-cart-rules-function-to-apply-discounts-by-percentage-of-original

Answer (score 3):

It can be done with the following code modification:

1) File

`app/code/core/Mage/SalesRule/Model/Validator.php` Copy to the local folder or create a custom module.

2) Function

```
protected function _getItemPrice($item)
{
    $price = $item->getQuote()->getStore()->convertPrice($item->getProduct()->getPrice());
    return $price;
}
```